# How to select all infromation including information that is in a seperate table together?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following problem: 
I am currently working with 3 tables , bw, mkz and wcn. 
bw is the main table I work with and mkz is some kind of link between the ids of bw and the categories in wcn ( web categorie names ). In wb one item can contain many categories and also none. 
My problem is that I simply dont understand how to select all categories for one id in bw. The problem is that I would need, in the best case, to get 30 lines of web items and each web item containing all its categories

bw contains the web ids and other information
mkz contains web ids and category ids and links them 
wcn contains category ids and names that need to be represented

My guess is that I somehow need to select in a select and count but I cant seem to find a possible solution to concat the category strings...

Comment: I guess you are looking for the  `GROUP_CONCAT` function, here are some examples of usage https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Comment: Exactly after I wrote my request I came upon the GROUP_CONCAT function! Thanks for the reply. Currently I am only struggling with the amount of information it outputs. I only get one id currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally, you want `group_concat()`.  Here is one method for retrieving all columns from `bw` along with the categories:

```
select bw.*,
       (select group_concat(wcn.name)
        from mkz join
             wcn 
             on mkz.category_id = wcn.category_id
        where mkz.web_id = bw.web_id
       ) as categories
from bw;
```

Comment: That's basically how I needed to solve it. Thanks! Group_Concat seems like a really interessting function ...